# What would 'cost of a coupon' vs 'value of a coupon' mean when optimizing budget for coupon allocation using LP in ride hailing context

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

When trying my hands on Linear Programming, came across an interesting problem [here](https://eng.lyft.com/how-to-solve-a-linear-optimization-problem-on-incentive-allocation-5a8fb5d04db1).

The article outlines using Linear Programming to optimise coupon allocation to riders/customers.

It defines the problem as :
[image: Problem Definition]

and primal problem as:

[image: Primal Problem]

My question is w.r.t understanding the context:

[image: value_vs_cost_of_coupon]

and the following preprocessing:

[image: preprocessing]

where:
$ \frac{c_{i1}}{v_{i1}} $ is the efficiency of the coupon

Now, if cost of coupon($c_{ij}$) is the price incurred to lyft and value $v_{ij}$ is the amount/revenue from that coupon for that customer , then for the following customer

$cust_1$ for coupon $c_1$ and $c_2$, say
$$ cost_1 = 100,cost_2 =100, \text{and }couponValue_1 = 500, couponValue_2 = 700 $$ i.e. coupons with same cost and different values, efficiency would be calculated as
$$ \frac{couponCost_{1}}{couponValue_{1}} = \frac{100}{500} = 0.20 $$
$$ \frac{couponCost_{2}}{couponValue_{2}} = \frac{100}{700} = 0.14 $$

This is in contrast my understanding of efficiency in this context, that a **higher value is better for efficiency**

Here Coupon $c_2$ is clearly better for the fact it creates more value for the same cost than coupon $c_1$ but the efficiency of coupon $c_2$ is lower (0.14) than that of coupon $c_1$ (0.20)

Am I missing the definitions of coupon cost and coupon value? or is it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traditional [greedy heuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Greedy_approximation_algorithm) for the knapsack problem considers the items in decreasing order of value per weight.  I agree that "efficiency" is a bad name for the reciprocal ratio of weight per value.